# Varnish not processing ESI for Wordpress back end

Tags: wordpress, varnish, esi, edge-side-includes

**Problem:**
It seems that Varnish (ver 3.0) is unable to process esi when the URL is called through Wordpress.

**Background :**
Idea is to cache article pages or for that matter any static page (of Wordpres site) for a longer duration, but for certain dynamic widgets. To achieve this, we set wrote a php page that will generate the sidebar and menu page through single.php and header.php. These will also include a header called 'Set-Esi'.

Varnish will process ESI if it detects presence of the header.

**Tests:** 
We added a php page in root of the site. Lets say 'esitest.php'. Inside this page we have the header, call to the widget menus and echo for date time for testing purpose.

PHP Test page [Code](http://pastebin.com/fQkcaZ5E)

Varnish VCL (under vcl_fetch, ver 3.0):

```
  if (req.http.host ~ "(dev.|beta.|beta1.)domain.com$") {
    ## Perform ESI TTL setting:
    if (beresp.http.Set-Esi){
      set beresp.do_esi = true;
      set beresp.ttl = 15m;
    }
    else if (req.url ~ "(esisidebar.php|esimenu.php|esimorefromcategory.php)") {
      set beresp.ttl = 3s;
    }
    else if (req.url ~ "^/wp-admin/admin-ajax.php") {
            set beresp.ttl = 3m;
    }
    else {
      set beresp.ttl = 5m; unset beresp.http.expires; unset req.http.Cookie;
    }
  }
```

**Outcome:**

1. Test php urls worked as expected. ie. `http://domain.com/esitest.php`
2. Wordpress urls did not process esi include. It displayed content under `esi:remove` tag. But ttl show 15 mins which is set if the header is present. This means that it goes through the loop in vcl that does esi processing.

Note: We use batcache with memcache storage, Nginx web server (gzip disabled).

Comment: What is the output of varnishlog when you do the wordpress test? From what you describe, I don't find anything wrong. We'll need more information on what's going on.

Comment: @BenjaminBaumann : The answer [here](http://stackoverflow.com/a/25421985/1764710) gave us a hint. So, we checked source code of article page of Wordpress site. First line is a blank line. We added an additional `<!DOCTYPE html>` to fill the void. Thereafter, ESI worked, but we encountered other issue--Article repeating itself over. At the moment, we are trying to get to the source of blank line.
Additionally, Varnish adds a cookie based on country mapping. I have excluded esi URLs from this match. However, that does not seem to be source of issue reported in the question.

Comment: We found the a plugin and corrected for blank line. But, ESI did not work eventhough the source began with '<'. We then repeated the step that made it work -- ie.  added `echo "<!DOCTYPE html>"` at the end of  wp-config.php. This makes ESI work. Now.. we are thoroughly confused!